# configuration changelog in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have a job in Jenkins which uses java 1.7. From build 23 onwards, it uses java 1.8 and from build 50 onwards it uses maven 3.3.9 instead of 3.3.6. Is there anyway i can store this information with date and timestamp ? I do not want to store all builds. I would like to keep a max of five.

Thanks

Comment: Found this: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/JobConfigHistory+Plugin. Any other suggestion is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative to the [JobConfigHistory](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/JobConfigHistory+Plugin) plugin that you already found, you may want to check the [Audit Trail](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Audit+Trail+Plugin) plugin.